# Switch input language depending on physical keyboard attached

Tags: keyboard, language, input-source

I use a swedish keyboard at home, and an english at work. I have one laptop for both places. Every day I have to switch the input language manually back and forth, and for every app I'm using it seems.

Is there any way to just have the input language match whatever keyboard I'm using, automagically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is "no".  The keyboard layout in force applies to all keyboards.  Are you already using the quick keyboard shortcut for switching keyboards?

I have heard that the keymapping app Karabiner can recognized different keyboards, but I haven't yet seen anyone use it to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This type of functionality is sometimes called location management. Basically, the machine determines its location using hints from network connections. In the Mac OS 9 days, Location Manager was built in to the OS. Not so with Mac OS X.

Here is a discussion of a similar capability, although I don't know how current it is:

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2010042707531680